# Push notification channel gets closed after phone reboot - Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am creating notification channel as:

```
HttpNotificationChannel channel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");  
channel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += channel_ShellToastNotificationReceived;  
channel.ChannelUriUpdated += channel_ChannelUriUpdated;  
channel.Open();  
channel.BindToShellToast();
```

Now HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel") gives me the Push Channel I created, even after I restart the app.

However, each time after phone restart, this method returns null.

Is it normal? Do I need to recreate my Push Channel every time after phone restart?

Comment: Yes, it is normal. You can send <wp:Param> in your xml, and your app will open right page with some params if user tap on notification.

Comment: @KalanjDjordjeDjordje Seems it is so. It'd be great if it was documented in MSDN site.